# How to benchmark TS

Tags: typescript, performance, benchmarking

I currently want to benchmark some of my TS code, But I find a strong behavior, I benchmark the same recursion code, but the time is hugely different. and always is the first benchmark code is the slowest, second one is the fastest.But the time should be same

```
export function benchmark(callback: CallableFunction, prefix: string) {
    const startStr = `${prefix}-start`;
    const endStr = `${prefix}-end`;
    performance.mark(startStr);
    callback();
    performance.mark(endStr);
    console.log(performance.measure(prefix, startStr, endStr));
}

function frecurive(n: number): number {
    if(n === 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if(n === 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    return frecurive(n-1) + frecurive(n-2);
}


function main() {
    benchmark(() => {
        frecurive(7);
    }, "all-inline");

    benchmark(() => {
        frecurive(7);
    }, "declarative");

    benchmark(() => {
        frecurive(7);
    }, "half-inline");
}

main();
```

I use `ts-node` for running ts code, maybe it is the problem.The benchmark result is :
[image]

Comment: You should heat up the code first by running it for a whole second, and then measure it by running it for at least a second. If you run in for 40ms JS engine won't want to optimize the code

Comment: tl;dr use bencharking lib see https://github.com/tinylibs/tinybench / https://vitest.dev/guide/features.html#benchmarking-experimental

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and offer me a solution, but may I ask why I need to run the program for a whole second before the benchmark? because I think that `perf_hook` can measure right thing by mark it.

Comment: https://v8.dev/blog/ignition-interpreter

Comment: V8 can run script in 3 modes - interpretating (which is slow), compiled (which takes time) and optimized (which takes even more time), so you have to run your code long enough for engine to choose to optimize it